# How to dispatch a action in React js after one action is completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my React JS project.

I am listing the restaurant list to the customers.
There are filters mainly the cuisine filter. Customers can select the cuisine and then data will be fetched from the API and re-rendered.

**Redux Store to store the data**

```
{
    restaurants: [],
    filters: {
        cuisines: []
    }
}
```

`restaurants: []` will store all the restaurant's data, while `cuisines: []` stores the filtered cuisine ids.

In `componentWillMount()` I have the logic which fetches the restaurants from the API and stores it inside the redux store.

At the same time, it will also check for the `cuisines: []` from store to get the filtered data from the API.

**Here is my filters component.**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {setSelectedCuisine, removeSelectedCuisine} from './../../actions/filterActions';
import {setRestaurants} from './../../actions/restaurantActions';

import {fetchRestaurants} from './../../utils/ApiLibrary';

import {loadJsLibraries} from './../../utils/LoadLibrary';

class Filters extends React.Component {

    lat = this.props.location.latitude;
    lng = this.props.location.longitude;
    maxDistance = 50;
    category = 'nearby';
    limit = 50;
    cuisineIds = this.props.filters.cuisines || [];
    restaurantAPI = '/gokhana/restaurant/categorized';

    cuisineStatus = (id) => {
        const cuisineFound = this.props.filters.cuisines.find((cuisineId) => {
            return cuisineId === id;
        });
        return cuisineFound ? true: false;
    }

    handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
        let isChecked = e.target.checked;
        isChecked ? 
            this.props.setSelectedCuisine(e.target.value) 
            : this.props.removeSelectedCuisine(e.target.value);

            fetchRestaurants(
                this.restaurantAPI,
                this.lat,
                this.lng,
                this.maxDistance,
                this.category,
                this.limit,
                this.cuisineIds
            ).then(result => dispatch(this.props.setRestaurants(result)));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-3">
                <div id="filters_col">
                    <a 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        href="#collapseFilters" 
                        aria-expanded="true" 
                        aria-controls="collapseFilters" 
                        id="filters_col_bt
                    "> 
                    Filters 
                        <i className="icon-plus-1 pull-right"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div className="collapse" id="collapseFilters">

                        <div className="filter_type">
                            <h6>Distance</h6>
                            <input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range"/>
                            <input type="text" id="range-test" value="" />

                            <h6>Food Type</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" className="icheck" />Veg Only</label></li>
                            </ul>
                            <h6>Outlet Type</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" className="icheck" />Restaurant</label></li>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" className="icheck" />Food Court</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="filter_type">
                            <h6>Cuisines</h6>
                            <ul className="nomargin">
                                {
                                    this.props.cuisines.map((cuisine) => {
                                        return (<li>
                                            <label className="checkbox-container">
                                                {cuisine.name}

                                                <input 
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    value={cuisine.id} 
                                                    className="cuisineCheckbox"
                                                    onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckBoxChange(e)}
                                                    {...this.cuisineStatus(cuisine.id) ? {checked: true} : {} }
                                                />
                                                <span className="checkmark"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>)
                                    })
                                }
                                {loadJsLibraries()}

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = {
    setSelectedCuisine,
    removeSelectedCuisine,
    setRestaurants
};

export default connect(state => state, mapStateToProps)(Filters);
```

I have multiple cuisines checkboxes, Now, when I check a checkbox then `setSelectedCuisines` action is dispatched, and if I uncheck a checkbox `removeSelectedCuisine` is dispatched.

This mechanism is working perfect, no problem.
Now, the actual problem is.

Whenever, `setSelectedCuisines` or `removeSelectedCuisines` gets called, after completion of this action, I want to call the API which fetches the restaurant data based upon the filters selected.

After calling API, I also want to dispatch the action `setRestaurants` which will set the restaurants in store.

In above component, you can see the `handleCheckBoxChange` dispatching the `setSelectedCuisines` and `removeSelectedCuisines`. And at the same time I am calling a function to fetch the restaurants from the API and dispatch the `setRestaurant`.

Problem here is that, the `setRestaurants` action gets called immediately after cuisines action gets called and I am not getting the correctly filtered data from the API.

I am worried about this, as I am not sure where and when can I call the `fetchRestaurants()` function so that I get filtered data.

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: No errors, but the data from API is fetched earlier before completing the action to update the `cuisines:[]` array in store, API needs the updated `cuisines:[]` array to get latest data.

Comment: can you show your restaurantActions.js ?

Comment: `export const setRestaurants = (restaurants) => ({
    type: 'SET_RESTAURANTS',
    restaurants
});`

Comment: No, here is the sequence, i) Select checkbox ii) dispatch `setSelectedCuisines` iii) Update the store iv) make api call and dispatch `setRestaurants()`. The problem is that before `setSelectedCuisines` updates the store, API is called and `setRestaurants` sets.

Comment: your API call in fetchRestaurants function right ?that means i want to see the fetchRestaurants function  for how did you make the api

Comment: There is no problem with `fetchRestaurants` and `setRestaurant`, problem is that in between two actions called,  before fetchRestaurants gets called, setSelectCuisines should update the cuisines array in store, and before updating the store, `fetchRestaurants` gets called which uses the old store data to fetch the API. So the problem is that I want to call the `fetchRestaurants` only when `setSelectedCuisines` action completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell you two ways to do this,

1. Add the logic for creating the array of selected cuisines in the handleChange() to a variable and use this value to Call the api and send the dispatch.
2. Use [pub-sub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) and inside your reducer, after merging with the existing cuisines in case of checkbox selection or removing old ones otherwise, and then call the pubsub PubSub.publish() to  call a function which fetches your api.

Comment: I did follow the first option to get the work done, and hopefully, it worked fine. Thanks man

Comment: Welcome. I too would have taken the first one as its easier. \m/

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch the function like below

```
this.props.dispatch(this.props.setRestaurants(result))
```